# How to make Ansible ignore changes in certain lines in file

Tags: ansible, virtual-machine

I have a regular ubuntu VM. My ansible playbook is the following

```
---
- hosts: linux
  tasks:
    - name: "Creating a file file.txt"
      become: yes
      copy: src=./file.txt dest=~/file.txt
      notify: restart some_app

  handlers:
    - name: restart some_app
      become: yes
      service:
        name=some_app
        state=restarted
```

And the contents of my file are

```
First line
Second line
```

After creating my VM I apply my ansible playbook. Then I am doing some work on ubuntu VM which could change the contents of file.txt (in Ubuntu VM, not in host). And when my work is done I apply anible playbook again. But I want to restart some_app *only* when changes are made to the *First line* in my file and *ignore* any changes made to the *Second line* (during some work in ubuntu VM). For example:

If after my work I have (on Ubuntu VM)

```
First line
Changed Second line
```

I want ansible to do nothing to this file (I don't want it to be replaced by initial file.txt on my host) and I don't want some_app to be started.

But if I have

```
Changed First line
Changed Second line
```

I want ansible to replace only *First line* and restart some_app, so after applying ansible playbook I would have

```
First line
Changed Second line
```

Is it possible to create Second line only once and then make ansible ignore it completly? How can I make this possible using ansible playbook? I can't split my file.txt into two different files or smth like this.

Comment: You might be able to get what you want using the [`lineinfile` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html), but a better choice would be to have Ansible deploy the appropriate configuration rather than manually editing a file you're also managing with Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [*backup*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-backup) and *diff* the first lines of the files.

For example, if the destination does not exist the module *copy* reports *changed* in the registered dictionary. The attribute *backup_file* is undefined. In this case, *changed_when* evaluates to *True* and the handler is notified

```yaml
    - copy:
        src: file.txt
        dest: ~/file.txt
        backup: true
      register: copy_result
      changed_when:
        - copy_result is changed
        - copy_result.backup_file is undefined
      notify: restart some_app
```

If the destination exists you want to notify the handler if the first line changes. Create the block below to test the first line. The tasks in the block will be executed only if a backup file is created

```yaml
    - block:
        - script:
            cmd: '{{ playbook_dir}}/diff_first_line {{ copy_result.backup_file }}'
            executable: /bin/bash
          register: diff_result
          ignore_errors: true
          changed_when: diff_result.stdout_lines.0|d('') == '1c1'
          notify: restart some_app
        - debug:
            var: diff_result
          when: debug|d(false)|bool
      when:
        - copy_result.backup_file is defined
```

Create the script below. The script returns the diff between the first lines of the destination *~/file.txt* and the backup file

```bash
shell> cat diff_first_line 
diff <(head -n 1 ~/file.txt) <(head -n 1 $1)
exit 0
```

Create the handler for testing

```yaml
  handlers:

    - name: restart some_app
      debug:
        msg: First line of ~/file.txt changed
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: test_24

  tasks:

    - copy:
        src: file.txt
        dest: ~/file.txt
        backup: true
      register: copy_result
      changed_when:
        - copy_result is changed
        - copy_result.backup_file is undefined
      notify: restart some_app
    - debug:
        var: copy_result
      when: debug|d(false)|bool

    - block:
        - script:
            cmd: '{{ playbook_dir}}/diff_first_line {{ copy_result.backup_file }}'
            executable: /bin/bash
          register: diff_result
          ignore_errors: true
          changed_when: diff_result.stdout_lines.0|d('') == '1c1'
          notify: restart some_app
        - debug:
            var: diff_result
          when: debug|d(false)|bool
      when:
        - copy_result.backup_file is defined

  handlers:

    - name: restart some_app
      debug:
        msg: First line of ~/file.txt changed
```

---

- If the destination does not exist the file will be created and the handler will be notified

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [test_24] *******************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
changed: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

TASK [script] ********************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
skipping: [test_24]

RUNNING HANDLER [restart some_app] ***********************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  msg: First line of ~/file.txt changed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_24: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_24 sudo cat /root/file.txt
First line
Second line
```

---

- If the destination exists and the first line changed

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_24 sudo cat /root/file.txt
First line changed
Second line
```

The script in the block will compare the first lines of the files and will notify the handler. Running the playbook with the variable *debug=true* gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e debug=true

PLAY [test_24] *******************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  copy_result:
    backup_file: /root/file.txt.1520674.2023-01-05@11:00:41~
    changed: false
    checksum: e23b0534d0708167023aba6f65ef83afe38d52df
    dest: /root/file.txt
    diff: []
    failed: false
    gid: 0
    group: root
    md5sum: cbfa34ef619be185bfbe2b8c8f104d97
    mode: '0644'
    owner: root
    secontext: system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0
    size: 23
    src: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1672934439.424632-1552928-229786621684419/source
    state: file
    uid: 0

TASK [script] ********************************************************************************
changed: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  diff_result:
    changed: true
    failed: false
    rc: 0
    stderr: |-
      Shared connection to test_24 closed.
    stderr_lines:
    - Shared connection to test_24 closed.
    stdout: |-
      1c1
      < First line
      ---
      > First line changed
    stdout_lines:
    - 1c1
    - < First line
    - '---'
    - '> First line changed'

RUNNING HANDLER [restart some_app] ***********************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  msg: First line of ~/file.txt changed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_24: ok=5    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- The handler won't be notified if the first line doesn't change

```bash
shell> ssh admin@test_24 sudo cat /root/file.txt
First line
Second line changed
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e debug=true

PLAY [test_24] *******************************************************************************

TASK [copy] **********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  copy_result:
    backup_file: /root/file.txt.1522339.2023-01-05@11:02:50~
    changed: false
    checksum: e23b0534d0708167023aba6f65ef83afe38d52df
    dest: /root/file.txt
    diff: []
    failed: false
    gid: 0
    group: root
    md5sum: cbfa34ef619be185bfbe2b8c8f104d97
    mode: '0644'
    owner: root
    secontext: system_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0
    size: 23
    src: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1672934567.8696983-1553096-127236704493791/source
    state: file
    uid: 0

TASK [script] ********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_24] => 
  diff_result:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    rc: 0
    stderr: |-
      Shared connection to test_24 closed.
    stderr_lines:
    - Shared connection to test_24 closed.
    stdout: ''
    stdout_lines: []

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_24: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```